Creating a load balancer fails and I have to start over
When I try to create a load balancer from the Google Cloud Console it fails and my progress is not saved.
The failure usually comes from a problem with an IP address. The error message usually states that the IP address is already assigned to another resource (is isn't) or that the IP address doesn't exist (it does).
The bigger problem is that I have to start from scratch every time. All the load balancer info I entered just disappears. Is there a way to do this so I can edit the load balancer info and try again rather than starting from the very beginning?
It seems like there surely is but being somewhat new to this I'm having trouble finding it.
I tried finding the console command that would've been run to create the load balancer and assign the IP addresses and such but did not see any type of "history" that displays this.

I encourage you to try to learn/use Google Cloud CLI. It's a command-line tool and it's initially more complex to use than a GUI but if you persist, the dividends will outweigh the cost. In your case, you can very easily rerun commands. Everything you can do in Console, you can with the CLI. Google generally always documents instructions using both the Console (GUI) and "gcloud" (an alias for the CLI). Here's the documentation for creating a load-balancer with both types of instruction
